# iCal Default Alarm

Tags: macos, calendar.app, alarm

How do I change the iCal default alarm from Message with Sound to just plain Message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible.

Comment: can you somehow confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

If you control click/right click on an event in iCal>Get Info, then click the "Edit" button in the bottom right hand corner, you should be able to change the alarm to just "Message".

Comment: This works for an individual event, but I want to change the default alarm in iCal so all future events use it rather than me having to change it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the sound setting in the iCal plist, you can affect the default. See a [description of steps](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080214211226511).  I suppose you would want to create a sound file (AIFF format) that was silent to replace the current one.